# Using Bert for long sentence

Tags: python, token, bert-language-model, embedding

I have a document which consist 200 rows(sentences). Each sentences has more than 512 tokens. I want to turn my whole document into a vector using Bert. But I am getting errors.

I have tried this,

```
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer
import torch
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sagorsarker/bangla-bert-base")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("sagorsarker/bangla-bert-base")
sentences = data['Text_stemmed_without_no']
input_ids_list = []
attention_mask_list = []
for sentence in sentences:
    encoded_dict = tokenizer.encode_plus(
                        sentence,
                        add_special_tokens = True,
                        return_attention_mask = True,
                        return_tensors = 'pt'
                   )
    input_ids_list.append(encoded_dict['input_ids'])
    attention_mask_list.append(encoded_dict['attention_mask'])
max_length = 512
stride = 256
bert_embeddings_list = []
for input_ids, attention_mask in zip(input_ids_list, attention_mask_list):
    num_windows = (len(input_ids) - 1) // stride + 1
    embeddings = []
    for i in range(num_windows):
        start_index = i * stride
        end_index = min(start_index + max_length, len(input_ids))
        window_input_ids = input_ids[start_index:end_index]
        window_attention_mask = attention_mask[start_index:end_index]
        with torch.no_grad():
            last_hidden_states = model(input_ids=window_input_ids.unsqueeze(0),       attention_mask=window_attention_mask.unsqueeze(0))
        window_embeddings = last_hidden_states[0][:, 0, :]
        embeddings.append(window_embeddings.numpy())
    bert_embeddings_list.append(np.concatenate(embeddings, axis=0))
bert_embeddings = np.array(bert_embeddings_list)
```

But I am getting error as

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-725c7332287b> in <cell line: 29>()
     36         window_attention_mask = attention_mask[start_index:end_index]
     37         with torch.no_grad():
---> 38             last_hidden_states = model(input_ids=window_input_ids.unsqueeze(0), attention_mask=window_attention_mask.unsqueeze(0))
     39         window_embeddings = last_hidden_states[0][:, 0, :]
     40         embeddings.append(window_embeddings.numpy())
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    972             raise ValueError("You have to specify either input_ids or inputs_embeds")
    973 
--> 974         batch_size, seq_length = input_shape
    975         device = input_ids.device if input_ids is not None else inputs_embeds.device
    976 
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Can anyone please let me know, what modify I need to do in this code.
I want a solution with explanation which can fix my problem

EDIT

---

I have tried this code

```
from transformers import BartTokenizer, BartModel
import torch
# Load the pre-trained tokenizer and model
tokenizer = BartTokenizer.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large')
model = BartModel.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large')
# encode the long texts
input_ids = []
attention_masks = []
for sentence in data['Text_stemmed_without_no']:
    encoded_dict = tokenizer.encode_plus(
                        sentence,                      # sentence to encode
                        add_special_tokens = True,     # add [CLS] and [SEP]
                        max_length = 600,            # maximum length of sentence
                        pad_to_max_length = True,      # pad sentence to maximum length
                        return_attention_mask = True,  # return attention mask
                        return_tensors = 'pt'          # return PyTorch tensor
                   )
    
    input_ids.append(encoded_dict['input_ids'])
    attention_masks.append(encoded_dict['attention_mask'])
# convert lists to PyTorch tensors
input_ids = torch.cat(input_ids, dim=0)
attention_masks = torch.cat(attention_masks, dim=0)
# get the BART embeddings
with torch.no_grad():
    last_hidden_states = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_masks)
# convert embeddings to numpy array
bart_embeddings = last_hidden_states[0][:,0,:].numpy()
```

But again and again kaggle session is getting turned off. Is it due to memory constraint? Kindly help me modifying the code

Comment: I do not have knowledge on BERT, but "Each sentences has more than 512 tokens" and "max_length = 512" do seems to have a relationship?

Comment: You probably just need to remove the `unsqueeze` from `---> 38             last_hidden_states = model(input_ids=window_input_ids.unsqueeze(0), attention_mask=window_attention_mask.unsqueeze(0))`

Comment: @Caridorc, I tried this, doesn't seem to work

Comment: "Is it due to memory constraint?"   Unknown because with your second attempt you did not provide the errors. (And it guessing what exactly changed....)